# error on starting user profile synchronisation service

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile

when i try to start my user profile synchronisation service  it take w while on "starting" statut then he return to "stopped" statut 
even the system service take the "automatiqe" statut type then he return to disable

Answer (score 1):

This is very much common error but differnt reason cause this. You should Check the ULS logs, Event Logs(Application, System, setup). that will help to identify the issue.

Here are couple of things to check:

- Make sure you are farm admin account(under which Sync Service is being started) is part of local admin on the sync servers.
- Reboot the Server after adding it to local admin( if account was not in the Local admin)
- From certificate store on the server make sure no duplicate FIM certs. for clean start, [delete all certs from their](http://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2010/08/15/more-user-profile-sync-in-sp2010-certificate-provisioning-issues/).
- Make sure their is no **one time** timer job related to User Profile Sync provision exist on sharepoint( check from central admin > monitoring> TImer Job).
- Put the FIM service as delayed Start.

[Rational Guide to implementing SharePoint Server 2010 User Profile Synchronization](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx)